# Help replicate graph with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I would like to emulate the same image I have attached. I would need to make the arrows thicker and add the text in brackets below each letter. If you could tell me what modifications I need to make to this code, I would appreciate it.

Best regards.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 1cm,
  mynode/.style={draw,circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center}
]

\node[mynode, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (a) {A};
\node[mynode, below right=of a, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (b) {J};
\node[mynode,right=of b, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (c) {S};
\node[mynode, below left=of a, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (e) {S};
\node[mynode, above right=of c, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (f) {A};
\node[mynode, below right=of f, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (d) {J};
\node[mynode, left=of e, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (g) {J};
\node[mynode, left=of g, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (h) {S};
\node[mynode, below=of h] (i) {U};
\node[mynode, below=of g,  fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (j) {Y};
\node[mynode, below=of c] (k) {U};
\node[mynode, below=of e] (l) {U};
\node[mynode, below=of b,  fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (n) {Y};
\node[mynode, below=of d,  fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (m) {Y};

\path (a) edge[-latex] (b);
\path (f) edge[-latex] (c);
\path (f) edge[-latex] (d);
\path (c) edge[latex-] (d);
\path (c) edge[-latex] (m);
\path (c) edge[latex-] (k);
\path (d) edge[-latex] (m);
\path (k) edge[-latex] (m);
\path (b) edge[-latex] (e);
\path (e) edge[latex-] (l);
\path (e) edge[-latex] (n);
\path (l) edge[-latex] (n);
\path (g) edge[-latex] (h);
\path (i) edge[-latex] (h);
\path (j) edge[latex-] (h);
\path (i) edge[-latex] (j);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Example.}
\label{fig:newgraph}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use `tikz-cd` to draw such diagrams in order to avoid some repetition. The style of the arrows is controlled by `every arrow/.style`, and you can use little tabulars for the node contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,shapes.geometric}
\tikzcdset{m/.style={column sep=0pt,
    every arrow/.style={draw,thick,-latex},
    /tikz/w/.style={fill=white},
    cells={nodes={ellipse,inner sep=0.5pt,fill=gray!30,draw,minimum height=3em}}}}  
\newcommand\mm[3][]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
   \ensuremath{#2}\\[-1.2ex]{\text{\tiny[#3]}}
   \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[m]
  & |[opacity=0]|\mm{A}{raza} & \\
   \mm{S}{blabla} \arrow[drr] & &\arrow[ll] \mm{J}{abcdef}\\
  |[w]| \mm{S}{blabla} \arrow[u] \arrow[rr]& & \mm{J}{abcdef}\\
\end{tikzcd}\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[m]
  & \mm{A}{raza}\arrow[dr] & \\
   \mm{S}{blabla} \arrow[drr] & &\arrow[ll] \mm{J}{abcdef}\\
  |[w]| \mm{S}{blabla} \arrow[u] \arrow[rr]& & \mm{J}{abcdef}\\
\end{tikzcd}\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[m]
  & \mm{A}{raza}\arrow[dl]\arrow[dr] & \\
   \mm{S}{blabla} \arrow[drr] & &\arrow[ll] \mm{J}{abcdef}\arrow[d]\\
  |[w]| \mm{S}{blabla} \arrow[u] \arrow[rr]& & \mm{J}{abcdef}\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

TikZ has several keys for setting the thickness of a line: `thick`, `very thick`, `ultra thick` (and similarly with `thin`). You can also set the width explicitly with e.g. `line width=1mm`.

As for the additional text, you could remove `text width=0.5cm` from the `mynode` style, and do e.g. `A\\[-4pt]\tiny(foobar)`. In the code below I defined a macro for this, but you don't have to do that.

Note I also added `on grid` to the `mynode` style, and increased the `node distance`. With `on grid` second node is placed such that the node centers are the `node distance` apart. Without `on grid` the `node distance` defines the distance between the borders of the nodes. The reason for this is to ensure that different size nodes are aligned properly.

Finally I used a loop for drawing all the arrows. Also not strictly necessary, but it shortens the code a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand\CwL[2]{% short for character with label
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
#1 \\[-4pt]
\tiny (#2)
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=2cm and 2cm,
  mynode/.style={draw,circle,align=center, inner sep=0pt, on grid}
]

\node[mynode, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (a) {\CwL{A}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below right=of a, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (b) {\CwL{J}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, right=of b, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (c) {\CwL{S}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below left=of a, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (e) {\CwL{S}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, above right=of c, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (f) {\CwL{A}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below right=of f, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (d) {\CwL{J}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, left=of e, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (g) {\CwL{J}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, left=of g, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (h) {\CwL{S}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below=of h] (i) {\CwL{U}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below=of g,  fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (j) {\CwL{Y}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below=of c] (k) {\CwL{U}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below=of e] (l) {\CwL{U}{foobar}};
\node[mynode, below=of b,  fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (n) {\CwL{Y}{foobarbaz}};
\node[mynode, below=of d,  fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (m) {\CwL{Y}{foobar}};


\foreach \x/\y in {a/b,f/c,f/d,d/c,c/m,k/c,d/m,k/m,b/e,l/e,e/n,l/n,g/h,i/h,h/j,i/j}
   \draw [ultra thick, -latex] (\x) -- (\y);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```